# Android local unit test - new View(null) returns null

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, null

I'm experimenting with local android tests (the ones that run on the local JVM, not on the device). I understand that classes in android.jar can't be used properly unless they are mocked, but for some reason when I try to instantiate a new View (or my own class that is inherited from the View)- I get null. This totally breaks my belief that "new" never returns null in Java.

Here's my test code (`src/test/java/com/example/FooTest.java`):

```
package com.example;

import android.view.View;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testView() {
        View v = new View(null);
        System.out.println("view = " + v);
    }
}
```

This code prints in the test report output that the view is null.

Here's my build.gradle (the rest of the project is just generated by `android create project` and is of no interest):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-22'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc2'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12+'
}
```

Can anyone give some clues about what kind of magic is happening here?

Comment: Shall I close this or it might serve for others who didn't think about implicit mocking of the `toString()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code only tells that the string representation (i.e. see `toString()` of `View`) is "null" not that `v` is `null`.

AFAIK, `new Something()` is **never** `null` in java

Comment: Yep, you're right. `returnDefaultValues` tells to return default values from each unmocked method (which is toString()), so it returns null. Strange that I haven't thought of it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, there's no mock involved in the posted code !?

Comment: Well, I'm not using mockito or any other mocks. However the android unit testing framework offers an `android.jar` mock for tests, which has all empty methods for all android classes. So I don't mock the View explicitly.

Comment: Some time ago `android.jar` in the SDK was throwing runtime exceptions when used on the desktop JVM. Now it can be configured to either throw exceptions, or to return default values in each method.